# How to pass param inside single quotes to a postgres query?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

In my node app, i need to run below query and and i'm passing parameters dynamically. But it's not fetching the parameters since they are referenced inside single quotes. Suggest a solution for this.

```
const text = `UPDATE glacier_restore_progress
            SET 
            status='completed',
            restore_end=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            restore_expire=DATE_TRUNC('minutes', current_timestamp + interval '$1 minutes')
            WHERE file_path = '$2' AND date_trunc('minutes', current_timestamp - interval '$1 minutes') <= restore_start`;

const values = [restoreDuration, fileKey];
await pool.query(text, values);
```

and the error i get is,

```
"bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement \"\" requires 0"
```

Comment: You need to add to your question the driver you are using and its version.

Comment: my pg version is "pg": "8.5.1"

Comment: Add that information to the question so other people don't need to search through the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely right; parameters cannot be inside quotes. There are a few ways we can solve this:

Taking the similarly broken example `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - start_date < INTERVAL '$1 years';`

1. Have the client submit the "full" value: `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - start_date < INTERVAL $1;`
2. Construct string in the query: `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - start_date < INTERVAL ($1 || ' years');`
3. (interval specific) Use the fact the unit can be specified as its own keyword: `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - start_date < INTERVAL $1 MINUTE`

My preference in this case is 1, however the most faithful to your question is 3. Be careful to use `MINUTE` and not `MINUTES`. Option 2, using the concatentation operator, is a good hack to have in your toolbelt. All answers tested in Postgres 13.

In addition to this, your parameter is likely going to bound as a number, which will get you an error. You may need to cast it to text, like so `$1::TEXT`

Your full query would be:

```
UPDATE glacier_restore_progress
SET
    status = 'completed',
    restore_end = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    restore_expire = DATE_TRUNC('minutes', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL $1::TEXT MINUTE)
WHERE file_path = $2
  AND DATE_TRUNC('minutes', current_timestamp - INTERVAL $1 MINUTE) <= restore_start
```

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
const text = `UPDATE glacier_restore_progress
        SET 
        status='completed',
        restore_end=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        restore_expire=DATE_TRUNC('minutes', current_timestamp + interval '1 minutes' * $1)
        WHERE file_path = $2 AND date_trunc('minutes', current_timestamp - interval '1 minutes' * $1) <= restore_start`;

const values = [restoreDuration, fileKey];
await pool.query(text, values);
```

this convention is mentioned here [refrence](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/2B704E31-B533-4159-B6F0-EC284CFE824C%40skype.net)